# Computer Modern vector fonts with meta-ness

Tags: fonts, metafont, computer-modern

Has anyone completed or seriously attempted a translation of the Computer Modern MetaFont sources into MetaType1 code that retains the family's meta-ness (i.e., ability to generate new fonts by modifying parameters)? The Latin Modern sources, for instance, appear to be more-or-less computer-generated with no meta-ness.

(I am aware that one of the reason such a translation would be difficult is that Knuth's CM programs use a lot of pen strokes whereas contemporary vector font formats use outlines.)

Comment: I've removed the `metapost` tag -- while MP is derived from MetaFont it has nothing to do with producing fonts.  https://texfaq.org/FAQ-MP

Comment: @Thruston I'm not sure where you got that idea. MetaPost inherits the font making capabilities of MetaFont and definitely can be used for making fonts. And the sources of the LM fonts are indeed MetaPost programs; they rely on `fontbase.mp` from MetaType1, which is not a valid MetaFont program.

Comment: I stand corrected -- thank you.  I [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaType1) that the MetaType1 tool is indeed based on MetaPost.  However, given how specialised it is, I think tagging this question `metapost` or even `metafont` is a bit misleading.  But if you feel you want to revert my edits, please go ahead.

Comment: A shame that no one has answered this.